# Identifying column for data in a csv fille in a Python dataframe statement

Tags: python, dataframe, date, names

I have tried many things to create a Python dataframe from 4 variables on a csv file: Date (mm/dd/yyyy format), floating point variables Reserves, FF, IORB. All tries result in error message that I haven't identified column with the data (apologies if my terminology is not correct). I found some easy errors to fix.  Now from a df.columns, the name of my df is rates, I see the correct data names Date, Reserves, FF, IORB. I even renamed the dataframe 'rates' names. But statements with these names are errors, that the variable isn't defined.  This is first time I've imported a CSV file into Python

```py
from datetime import datetime   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import dateparser 
d= lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%w/%Y')  
dateparse = lambda x: d(x) 
rates = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Research/SOMA/SomaFinal.csv','./data.txt', index_col=[0],\ usecols=[0,1,2,3],skiprows=6, parse_dates=['Date'])) 
print(rates.columns) 
rates.info()  
rates = rates.rename(columns={'rates[1]': 'Reserves', 'rates[2]': 'FF', 'rates[3]': 'IORB'})
print(FF)
```

**ERROR: File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Research\SOMA\soma.py", line 27, in 
print(FF)
NameError: name 'FF' is not defined

Output:

```
Index(['Date', 'WRESBAL', 'FF', 'IORB'], dtype='object')
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1999 entries, 0 to 1998
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------   --------------  -----         
 0   Date     1992 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 1   WRESBAL  1992 non-null   float64       
 2   FF       1992 non-null   float64       
 3   IORB     39 non-null     object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 62.6+ KB
6


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

RangeIndex: 2005 entries, 0 to 2004
```

Comment: Please [format your question properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The output you shared does not appear to be the output of the script as you shared it. Can you also share the first few lines of the .csv you are reading? (anonymised, if needed)

Comment: Thank you.  I Just reran a change in the code, after your question.  The code now matches the output.

Comment: Lines from csv:  Date WRESBAL FF IORB
lin Billions of U.S. Dollars Percent Percent\n
W Weekly, Ending Wednesday Weekly, Ending Wednesday Daily, 7-Day
1/1/1900 1984-01-04 to 2022-03-02 1954-07-07 to 2022-03-02 2021-07-29 to 2022-03-04
Liabilities and Capital: Other Factors Draining Reserve Balances: Reserve Balances with Federal Reserve Banks: Week Average   
Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System (US)   
Date WRESBAL FF IORB
1/4/1984 22.3 10.1 
1/11/1984 21.4 9.5 
1/18/1984 21.5 9.5 
1/25/1984 20.9 9.5 
2/1/1984 20.8 9.4

Comment: How do you separate lines in overstack?  Above comment merges all data rows.  Tried double enter, \n.  Didn't work